# Quotes with HTML attribute problem showing up in Google's data highlighter

Tags: google-search-console, html, structured-data

We have a Bengali website and there are some category pages for art and literature.
[image]
When we are using any narration with "example" quotes, it's showing errors in Google Search Console Data Highlighter for HTML attribute error issues. I have to use these kinds of narration of some Poet's of poems and also novels.

How can I use quotes properly without any errors in Google Search Console Data Highlighter?

Comment: Can you provide an example + quote/screenshot the error message?

Comment: The screenshot would help me understand what is going on.   It may just be a matter of escaping quotes with their HTML entities in some places.   `"` sometimes needs to be written as `&quot;`.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using only straight quotes, or only curly quotes. Don't mix the two. You may need to experiment with both types. (For example, Google Structured Data Testing Tool only accepts straight quotes in JSON-LD files, and throws an error otherwise.)